# OLEDB Source Task Failing

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2008, ssis

I have a DataFlow task that is supposed to extract around 18 million records and after performing some tasks on them, insert them into another OLEDB Destination.

The problem can be seen in the screenshot below.
[image: SSIS Package]

The errors that I receive are like:

> Information: The buffer manager has allocated 65536 bytes, even though
>   the memory pressure has been detected and repeated attempts to swap
>   buffers have failed.

I tried changing DefaultBufferMaxRows from 10000 as it was originally set to 100000 and even 150000, but it didn't work out and increasing the number lead to even less records coming through the Source 3 million and 1 million respectively as opposed to 8 million when the value was at 10000.

I would appreciate if someone could help me out in this.

Comment: Could it be a timeout on the source? What is your source DB? It doesn't look like you are having any blocking components in your package. Also, with a multicast, you are trying to write twice as many records in your destination. Is that intended?

Comment: Yeah the multicast is a necessary component. Its not a timeout. Source and Destination DB are SQL Servers.

Comment: Try TOP 100 rows & see if it works

Comment: What are the properties on your OLE DB destination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all those stumbling upon this question later on,

I solved it by increasing DefaultBufferSize in Data Flow Task's properties from 10485760 to 104857600.

The package took around 10 hours to complete but it completed without any glitches, although there were a few warnings regarding full buffers.